# systemd service - celery.platforms.LockFailed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/celery/worker1.pid'

Tags: linux, service, systemd

I noticed that `celery` is not working so I checked service status and it said this:

```
celery.platforms.LockFailed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/celery/worker1.pid'
```

So I've created a `celery` folder inside `/var/run/` and changed it's ownership to `myuser:www-data`.

It seemed to be working but it happened again. The same with `celerybeat` service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service (Worker)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=futilestudio
Group=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/celeryd
WorkingDirectory=/home/futilestudio/project
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `celery` folder disappeared again. Do you know what is wrong with that?

Comment: same problem here! any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585592/running-celery-as-daemon-does-not-create-pid-file